# Change element style CSS onclick?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I don't know why my CSS does not work here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ab9p5qtq/) , I tried focus but when I click around even if it is not a link the effect goes away?

```
<div class="footer-container">
    <ul>
        <li id="color"><a href="#">English(US)</a></li>

    </ul> 

</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#color").click(function(){
    $(this).css("color", "black");
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `$("#color")` you are targeting the parent of your concerned element. Use `$("#color a")`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#color a").click(function(){

    $(this).css("color", "black");
});
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bh58c1pf/

Or you can do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#color").click(function(){

        $(this).children().eq(0).css("color", "black");
    });
    });
```

But it would be slower